# this.setState is not a function, and .bind(this) is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, this

The issue I am having is that I am unable to call `this.setState` inside of the callback of an external library's method, and I also cannot bind to that method.

I am using a library called html2canvas, and I need to access the state of the class I'm using one of the methods in.

Here is my class:

```
class Test extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  componentDidMount() {

    html2canvas(document.getElementById("target"), {
        onrendered: function (canvas) {

          var base64image = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
          document.body.appendChild(canvas);
          this.setState({canvas: canvas} );
        },
        width:320,
        height:220
    }).bind(this);
  }
}
```

This returns the following errors:

```
Inline Babel script:23 Uncaught TypeError: html2canvas(...).bind is not a function
    at Hello.componentDidMount (<anonymous>:22:8)
    at commitLifeCycles (react-dom.development.js:17469)
    at commitAllLifeCycles (react-dom.development.js:18871)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:143)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:193)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:250)
    at commitRoot (react-dom.development.js:19083)
    at react-dom.development.js:20553
    at unstable_runWithPriority (react.development.js:735)
    at completeRoot (react-dom.development.js:20552)
```

which is on the `.bind(this)` call.

```
Inline Babel script:19 Uncaught TypeError: this.setState is not a function
    at Object.onrendered (<anonymous>:18:14)
    at Object.o.complete (html2canvas.min.js:8)
    at o (html2canvas.min.js:7)
    at Object.u.Preload (html2canvas.min.js:7)
    at html2canvas.min.js:8
```

You can view the example on the JSFiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/michael_t/6q34ofws/125/

Comment: check this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/t8m45y93/

Comment: You have the `.bind` in the wrong place.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/6Ltsmjof/2/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first issue is that you are using `.bind(this)` in the wrong place, it should be bound to the anonymous function that runs `onrendered`.

However, there is no need to bind `this` to the function, if you instead change to an arrow function so that your function does not bind `this` to itself but will refer to the `Class`.

```
html2canvas(document.getElementById("target"), {
     onrendered: (canvas) => {
          ...
          this.setState({canvas: canvas} );
        },
     ...
})
```